# Regex to find numbers in brackets, and also trim first match whitespace

Tags: regex

I have text strings with "name (number)".

I have the following regex that works `(.*)\((.*)\)` and would return the first element as `name` and second as `number`.

However I need to strip the whitespace from " name " and using `(\S.*\S)\((.*)\)` but only matches if there is whitespace.

I would like to strip whitespace, if any, and return `name` (stripped of left/right whitespace) and `number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
(\S*)\s*\((\d*)
```

The first group contains the name without any whitespaces. The second group captures the string of digits. (Assuming that `number` will actually be text that contains numbers).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7cqfWB/3)

Answer (score 0):

What about `\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*)\)`  -> this will take name before first space, however you can remove `?` if you want greedy search