# .NET regex match returning too many elements

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Per [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70409752/regex-to-find-numbers-in-brackets-and-also-trim-first-match-whitespace), I use the following regex to parse `name (100)` the name from the number in brackets, to give:

1. Name to the left of the opening bracket, with whitespace left/right stripped
2. The number in the brackets

With my C# code:

```
var found = Regex.Match("morleyc (1005)", @"(\S*)\s*\((\d*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

I get an array of 3 items, whereas I would expect a 2 element array containing the 2nd and 3rd items only:

```
morleyc (1005
morleyc
1005
```

This is what I expect (as as per [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5CS*%29%5Cs*%5C%28%28%5Cd*%29&i=hello%20%28100%29) elements):

```
morleyc
1005
```

Please advise what I am doing wrong in my code?

.net fiddle @ https://dotnetfiddle.net/5DVWPs

Comment: Probably `@"(\w+)\s*\([0-9]+\)"` pattern,  where `\w+` - one or more word (letters or digits) for name, then `\s*` for optional whitespaces and `\([0-9]+\)` for number

Comment: Please see [my answer to another question on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27444808/546871) where I try and show how to understand the results of regex searches in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you want

```
 @"(?<name>\w+)\s*\((?<number>[0-9]+)\)"
```

pattern, where

```
 \w+        - one or more word (letter or digit) characters for name
 \s*        - optional (zero or more) whitespaces
 \([0-9]+\) - one or more digits in parenthesis for number
```

Note *named capturing groups*:

```
 (?<name> ... )    - part of the match which stands for name
 (?<number>  ... ) - -/- stands for number
```

If name can contain letters only (no digits are allowed) you can put

```
 @"(?<name>\p{L}+)\s*\((?<number>[0-9]+)\)"
```

pattern, where `\p{L}` stands for a *unicode* letter

**Demo:**

```
var found = Regex.Match(
  "morleyc (1005)", 
 @"(?<name>\w+)\s*\((?<number>[0-9]+)\)", 
   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        
Console.WriteLine($"Name: {found.Groups["name"].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"Number: {found.Groups["number"].Value}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
Name: morleyc
Number: 1005
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G9Rb0O)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry for the reply. Your fiddle gives the original string, and the name. I have updated my question to show the expected output elements (name, number)

Comment: @morleyc: I see; I've added *named groups* `name` and `number` into the pattern for you to extract `morleys` and `1005` easily. I've edited both the answer and the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The `morleyc (1005` part in the result is the full match. The pattern is also not matching the closing `)`

You could check if there is a match, and if there is,  get the group 1 and group 2 values only.

**Note** that in the pattern, almost everything is optional except `(` so it can also match a single `(`

```
var found = Regex.Match("morleyc (1005)", @"(\S*)\s*\((\d*)\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (found.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(found.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(found.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

See the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TvubYs).

Output

```
morleyc
1005
```

[image]

A bit more specific pattern could be:

```
(\S+)[\p{Zs}\t]+\(([0-9]+)\)
```

- `(\S+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `[\p{Zs}\t]+` Match 1 or more spaces (`\s` can also match a newline)
- `\(([0-9]+)\)` Capture group 2, match 1+ digits 0-9 between matchint the `(` and `)`

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cS%2b%29%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d%2b%5c%28%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%5c%29&i=name+%28100%29)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Per my understanding from the docs it would return the second and third elements only... I'm ok to skip over the first but seems i shouldn't need to if my regex were matching correctly?

Comment: @morleyc The first element is the full match, the second one is the value of capture group 1 and the 3rd is the value of capture group 2.

Answer (score 1):

You did it correctly. According to [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=net-6.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Match_Groups):

> the first element of the GroupCollection object (the element at index
> 0) returned by the Groups property contains a **string that matches the
> entire regular expression pattern**

So, regex pattern with 2 groups will return 3 results:

1. string that matches the pattern
2. 1st group
3. 2nd group